# What happens to data stored in my local MySQL workbench when a website is taken live?

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, backend

if for instance I have a form in my website which when filled stores the input data to my local mysql workbench based on the php code that enables access to the database. What becomes of this database when I decide to take the website live? Seeing us unlike the `.CSS`, `.JS` and `.PHP` files that can be put in one folder and uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench does not store any of your data. It's a client like many others (e.g. the MySQL shell). You should read up on the [client-server-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) concept to understand how the MySQL server and a client like MySQL Workbench work.